# How do I make the handle of the kettle?

Tags: edit-mode

My goal is to simply make the handle of the kettle:

[image]

If I have to be specific then the handle should have both ends equal in size and perfectly is put into the model.

I have thought and tried of two solutions but all of them failed.:

1. Extrude faces from the top head of the kettle and the bottom face of the kettle (consider it as a face with it's part containing the text "Dowell") and then right click and click bridge edges with me using loop cuts to make it have a curve.

Problem:
This does not give both ends equal in size as one will be larger (bottom face of the kettle) and the smaller one (top head kettle face).

2. Create a cylinder cut it in half and then snap it to the kettle with it also being curved by loop cuts.

Problem: It also does not give both ends of the handle equal in size with an added part of what face to snap it into.

An idea, suggestion or an answer can help, thanks.

Comment: Plenty of YT videos showing how to model cup handles on the web. Just scale up or down the loops at the top and/or bottom of the handle to match the size in the image. For instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBtDix7xGOg&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U) part of the infamous donut tutorial (2.8 version).

Answer (score 0):

The best is probably to draw an edge along the shape, then extrud inwards to get something like this:

[image]

Then extrude:

[image]

We don't have any other view so it's hard to know what are the thickness but you'll probably need to scale some parts:

[image]

Then bevel the edges, etc:

[image]

[image]